# React Meteor render HTML with JS

Tags: html, reactjs, meteor, react-redux, react-helmet

I have a main.js file

**main.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { renderRoutes } from '../imports/startup/client/routes.jsx'

Meteor.startup(() => {

  render(renderRoutes(), document.getElementById('target'));


});
```

and an index.html file which contains the divider "target"

**index.html**

```
<head>
   <body>
     <div id="target" />
   </body>
</head>
```

**How can I remove the HTML file and render it on the main.js file as I need it for react-helmet.**

Comment: I don't understand what you need help with. Do you want an implementation of using react-helmet?

Comment: @JamesOshomah Yes please that would be so great.. I'm stuck here for hours.

Comment: `ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<Handler />);
const helmet = Helmet.renderStatic();`

Comment: What is the <Handler /> here..